# Virtualbox 5.0 - install error (your system has not been modified)

Tags: virtualbox

I would like to install the Vbox 5.0 on windows 10 (pro insider preview), but I got an error message durring the installation.

> Your system has not been modified

What can I do? What should be the problem?
Where could be the log file with more details about that error message?

I found the answer for that problem with same error message but I could not use it.

> change the "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Network\MaxFilters" from 8 to 20

There is no any data with that name.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved with time.
I received an upgrage from microsoft. Maybe I got the final version of windows 10. After that the installation was successful.